# Using st_geometry functions inside query statements in ADO.net?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial

I have ArcSDE 10 and Oracle 11g installed on my Windows server 2003. And i am trying to query tables having st_geoemtry columns.and i have got the results when i am querying from SQL Developer, and queries are working fine. But when i am trying to access and filling into DataSet in c# using ADO.NET it is throwing exception like "Un supported data format" for st_geometry column.

Actually my main objective is querying oracle (ArcSDE) using C#. If anybody have any idea over this please share with me or at least some suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully someone will post an answer with code sample with using custom data types (ST_GEOMETRY)--I'm almost certain it is possible but I haven't done it.

I rarely access the actual geometry outside of ArcObjects, but when I do--I usually will convert to WKB in the select statement with a [ST_AsBinary](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/ST_AsBinary/006z0000003t000000/) which will load into `byte[]` and then I convert back to IGeometry in c#.

It's a quick&dirty method--not the best method.